# Avoid reload view after orientation change

Tags: android

I am new to android development . I have been puzzled by this problem in recent times .
 Every time orientation changes my view gets reloaded. I want to avoid this. This is happening   on change from landscape to portrait and vice versa.

Comment: It must get reloaded to stay the correct size for the new layout.

Answer (score 1):

Put below line in your manifest in activity:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

So, your activity should look like:

```
<activity
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:name=".YourActivity"/>
```

This way prevent destroying activity on orientation changes.

Comment: This way works for sure. Probably you can post some code to understand your issue?

Comment: i am stuck on this issue as to why the view is loading on orientation change when the view was already loaded before orientation change....

Comment: Probably you are doing smth wrong in your code. Create simple project and apply my solution. you will see, that this approach works

Answer (score 0):

The reason why Android is reloading the view after the orientation has changed is that this view is most probably another view than the one that was displayed before the orientation change happened, e.g. with new layout, font sizes, imageviews or other resources. The Android system is able to automatically load suitable resources for different screen dimensions (e.g. height, width, density ... ) in case of an orientation change.

For this to happen, Android first calls the activity's `onDestroy()` method, followed by a call to its `onCreate()` method to enable the activity to reload resources and activity state.

If for some reason you do not want this behaviour, you can follow the above advice and add an `android:configChanges` attribute to your activity element. In this case Android calls the activity's `onConfigurationChanged()` method instead of `onDestroy()` and `onCreate()`. `onConfigurationChanged()` is the method to place your code to adapt to the new orientation, if necessary. If not, it can also be left empty.

For further reading, see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html